# how to run at the same time imageClick() and onTouchEvent()?

Tags: android

I have this image in the xml (and others elements):

```
        <ImageView
        android:clickable="true"  
android:onClick="imageClick" 
        android:id="@+id/Decena0"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

I want to run the two next methods when I press on the image and I don't lift my finger:
First:

```
public void imageClick(View view) {  
//Implement image click function  
Log.e("Example", "Imagen clickada");
}
```

Second:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//Coordenadas
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();

switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    break;
}   
return true;
    }
```

How I can do it? Because if I press on the image and lift my finger on the image, only runs the first method (I understand it perfectly), but if I press on the image and I don't lift a finger and move my finger, not running any method. If I click somewhere else where there is no image the second method work well.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29):

> Returns
>
> True if the event was handled, false otherwise.

So, when your method returns `true`, the other events won't fire. If you want any click listeners to run also, try returning `false`.

Comment: ok, thanks. But I can't execute the second method in any way when I press the image?

Comment: What are you overriding `onTouchEvent` on? A ViewGroup that has your ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `public abstract boolean onLongClick (View v)` 
Called when a view has been clicked and held.
Parameters:
v  The view that was clicked and held. 
Returns:
true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

or something like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,  MapView map) { //this is for map on touch
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            start = e.getEventTime();
            int x = (int) e.getX();
            int y = (int) e.getY();
            touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);

        }

        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            stop = e.getEventTime();
        }
        if (stop - start > 2000) { //your code on long touch, in this case more than 2 sec
     }
            });
```